# How to pass ransack param[:q] object to another method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I am trying to pass my ransack params[:q] object to my presenter class but getting the `No Ransack::Search object was provided to search_form_for!` error.

Here is my sample code

**client_managers_widgets/index.html.haml**

```
= search_form_for @search, :url => admin_client_managers_widgets_path do |f|
  = render :partial => "admin/share/filter_wrapper", :locals => { :f => f, :filter=> "admin/client_managers_widgets/filters/redemption_filter" }
```

**_redemption_filter.html.haml**

```
%table.filters
  %tr
    %td
      = f.label :created_at_gteq, "Select Period"
      = f.select :created_at_gteq, { "Start Till Date" => "", "This Year" => Date.today.beginning_of_year, "Last Month" => 1.month.ago.beginning_of_month, "This Month" => Date.today.beginning_of_month }
    %td
      = f.label :user_telecom_circle_regional_managers_id_eq, "Region"
      = f.collection_select :user_telecom_circle_regional_managers_id_eq, @telecom_regions.select_options, :id, :region, {:include_blank => t(:all)}, :class => 'telecom_circle_regional_managers_id_eq'
  %tr
    %td
      = f.label :created_at_date_gteq,"Select Custome Time"
      = f.text_field :created_at_date_gteq, :class => 'datepicker input-small'
      = f.label "-", :class=>"to"
      = f.text_field :created_at_date_lteq, :class => 'datepicker input-small'
```

**controller => client_managers_widgets**

```
def index
     @client_manager_dashboard = ClientManagerDashboard.new(current_admin_user, search_params)
     @users = @client_manager_dashboard.get users
   # .
  # .
  # .
end

private

def search_params
  params[:q]
end
```

**presenter => client_manager_dashboard**

```
class ClientManagerDashboard
  def initialize(admin_user, search_params)
    @current_ability = Ability.new(admin_user)
    @search_params = search_params
  end

  def get_users
    @search = User.joins(:client).where(clients: {id: clients}).search(search_params)
    @users = @search.result
  end
  private

  def current_ability
    @current_ability
  end

  def search_params
    @search_params
  end
end
```

Right now I just added basic code snippet but it is the generalized scenario.
Please let me know any one has implemented this type of scenario.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with `binding.pry`? Also does ransack take `params[:q]` or just `params`? Lastly, have you tried passing `@search_params` to search on its own?

Comment: @MikeManfrin, yes I passed `@search_params` to the search and it is working perfect.

Comment: That confirms my hunch; try making your search_params method return `@search_params ||= @search_params`

Comment: @MikeManfrin, I tried it but getting same type of issue. I am thinking it because I didn't mentioned  **Search object (like @search=Product.search(params[:q]) )** in the controller action.

Answer (score 3):

you need a spell Flat Scope, like this

```
def define_methods
 shared = 0
 Kernel.send :define_method, :counter do
  shared
 end
 Kernel.send :define_method, :inc do |x|
  shared += x
 end
end
```

you can read 《Metaprogramming Ruby》

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me `@search` variable is nil in this code:

```
= search_form_for @search, :url => admin_client_managers_widgets_path do 
|f|
```

Because `@search` is an instance variable of `ClientManagerDashboard`.  For example this should work:

```
class ClientManagerDashboard
  .. 
  def get_search
    @search = User.joins(:client).where(clients: {id: clients}).search(search_params)
  end
  ..
end
```

And in your view:

```
= search_form_for @client_manager_dashboard.get_search, :url => admin_client_managers_widgets_path do |f|
```

Comment: Tried your solution but getting undefined method `get_users' for nil:NilClass

Comment: also one quick question, one of my method (also where I implemented your solution) is returning an json object (which is manually created) not any instance of the ransack object then what should I do?

Comment: `JSON.parse(your_json).to_query` will you the json in url parameters format. So you can do `.search(JSON.parse(your_json).to_query)`